# How to create a BMI Calculator from Batch

Tags: batch-file

I am new to programming.
I was trying to create a BMI(Body Mass Index) Calculator in Batch but its not working, please help me, tell my mistakes and tell the code(if possible)

```
 @echo off
echo ---------------------------------------
echo Welcome to BMI Calculator..........
echo ---------------------------------------
echo Programmer- Anuj
set/p Your Weight=
set/p Your Height
set/a BMI=%Weight%/%Height%*%Height%
echo BMI
IF BMI>18 echo You are Underweight
IF BMI<18 >25 Your weight is perfect in reference to Height.
IF BMI<25 You are Overweight
pause
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. SOF is not a tester site for your code. Please, ask a specific problem about it, and provide what error are you getting for.

Comment: Please elaborate on "not working"! Are you aware that batch can only do integer arithmetics?

Comment: `BMI=%Weight%/%Height%*%Height%` will result in just `BMI=%Weight%`. Use `BMI=%Weight%/%Height%/%Height%` or `BMI=%Weight%/(%Height%*%Height%)`

Answer (score 1):

Well, this code works for me:

```
@echo off
echo ---------------------------------------
echo Welcome to BMI Calculator..........
echo ---------------------------------------
set/p Weight=Your Weight in integer Kg: 
set/p Height=Your Height in meters an *two* centimeters: 
set/a BMI=%Weight%*10000/(%Height:.=%*%Height:.=%)
echo BMI = %BMI%
IF %BMI% leq 18 echo You are Underweight
IF %BMI% gtr 18 IF %BMI% leq 25 echo Your weight is perfect in reference to Height.
IF %BMI% gtr 25 IF %BMI% leq 30 echo You are Overweight
IF %BMI% gtr 30 echo You are Obese
pause
```

This is what I did:

- I consulted the syntax of `SET /P` command, that appear in tons of sites in the web (like [this one](https://ss64.com/nt/)) or directly in my computer via `SET /?` command, and realized that the original commands are wrong, so I rewrote them accordingly to the usage format.
- I did the same with the rest of commands and rewrote them all.
- I reviewed the method for Body Mass Index calculation at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index) and adjusted the formula in `SET /A` command, so it gives right results.

I don't know why you could not access the same information from your computer. Perhaps it have a communication problem, or perhaps it is much simpler for you to just post a question here instead... **`:(`**